# Move location of text in a box in html

Tags: html, hover, caption

Trying to implement a hover over caption over an image where an opaque overlay appears with words but am having a bit of trouble.

My code is below:

```
<style type="text/css">
  a.hovertext {
    position: relative;
    width: 220px;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    text-align: center;
  }
  a.hovertext:after {
    content: attr(data-title);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 5px;
    padding: 0em 0px;
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s;
    -o-transition: 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: 0.5s;
  }
  a.hovertext:hover:after, a.hovertext:focus:after {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
</style>

<a class="hovertext" data-title="Europe 2014" href="URL"><img alt="" border="0" src="URL" height="220" width="220" /></a>
```

The idea is how I want it but I can't figure out how to move the text to the middle of the box vertically so that it's completely centered and how to change the size and style of the font.

Any ideas? I'm sure it's an easy modification but I'm not very good at html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `line-height`, you can use this to achieve your goal:

```
display: -webkit-box; /* OLD: Safari,  iOS, Android browser, older WebKit browsers.  */
display: -moz-box; /* OLD: Firefox (buggy) */
display: -ms-flexbox; /* MID: IE 10 */
display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW, Chrome 21–28, Safari 6.1+ */
display: flex; /* NEW: IE11, Chrome 29+, Opera 12.1+, Firefox 22+ */

-webkit-box-align: center; 
-moz-box-align: center;
-ms-flex-align: center;
-webkit-align-items: center;

justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
align-items: center; /* align vertical */
```

Updated with the `font-size` and `font-family`: http://jsfiddle.net/Q6jLX/2/ (updated to have the compatibility also with IE10 with `-ms-flexbox`)

I have added this:

```
a.hovertext:after {
    .......
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    .......
}
```

and imported google font: `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

My hint is to download the font that you need and then use it.

**----------- ANOTHER METHOD WITHOUT `FLEX` AND `LINE-HEIGHT` ------------**

I do not know if you are using a plugin or you are coding everything by yourself, if `data-title` is not mandatory, here another method: http://jsfiddle.net/Q6jLX/3/

`display: table-cell` compatibility: [http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/display:table-cell](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/display%3atable-cell)

Comment: with this method, also when you change the width or the height of your box, the text will be always in the middle of it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a revised code of your sample. Check on a.hovertext:after where I added line-height to it

```
  a.hovertext {
    position: relative;
    width: 220px;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    text-align: center;
  }
  a.hovertext:after {
    content: attr(data-title);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 5px;
    padding: 0em 0px;
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s;
    -o-transition: 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: 0.5s;
    line-height: 220px;
  }
  a.hovertext:hover:after, a.hovertext:focus:after {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `line-height` to following class:

```
a.hovertext {
    position: relative;
    width: 220px;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 220px;
  }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tAqHk/)

Also for size you can use `font-size` and for for font style you can you `font-family` like following example:

[example with font size and font family](http://jsfiddle.net/tAqHk/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This would work as well - added padding:

```
<style type="text/css">
  a.hovertext {
    position: relative;
    width: 220px;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    text-align: center;
  }
  a.hovertext:after {
content: attr(data-title);
position: absolute;
left: 0;
/* bottom: 5px; */
padding: 102px 70px;
/* width: 220px; */
/* height: 220px; */
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
text-decoration: none !important;
color: #fff;
opacity: 0;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 100%;
-webkit-transition: 0.5s;
-moz-transition: 0.5s;
-o-transition: 0.5s;
-ms-transition: 0.5s;
  }
  a.hovertext:hover:after, a.hovertext:focus:after {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. for clarification: to center the content vertically you should give the div the same value for the attributes `line-height` and `height`

> ```
>   a.hovertext:after {
>             height: 220px;
>             line-height: 220px;
>         }
> ```

this is a cross browser solution. 
 2. to change the size of the font you should change the value of `font-size` or `font-weight`or `font-style` (e.g. `font-size:25px; font-weight:bold; font-style:italic`)
For documentation refer [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp)

Comment: Works well, thanks! Is there a way to split the content in 'data-title' in to two lines? <br/> doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @TLC is your attribute always plain text?

Comment: try with \A caracter to insert a newline inside css content. e.g. data-title="Europe \A 2014", Let me know if works for you

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Though I did notice that if I had a very long line, the new line would be over 100px down away from the first line. Do you know why this is so and if there is a way to make them closer?

Comment: This massive space doesn't seem to be a problem when implementing Mark's code instead of line-height...interesting

Comment: Hello @faby, please check my updated answer and here the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q6jLX/3/

Comment: So you fixed the problem?